# Help with writing a proof with unique and rational/irrational

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

prove that for every rational number z and every irrational number x, there exists a unique irrational number y such that x+y=z
 I have seen this solved before however I am not looking to solve this using gcd. The unique portion is messing me up. I'm not sure if I should set this up as a if p then q. im confused on how to set it up. I understand a rational sum is possible if both are rational. Any suggestions would be great as to how to go about the problem. Thank you!
 I have something like 
     Let X not in Q and z in Q such that X+y=z. 
    Then I get stuck because I don't know if I should verfy the existence of just one y but first picking two different y values.

Comment: Think about it this way: What would $y$ have to be? What value do we KNOW that $y$ is?

Comment: Why not split this into two parts. Start with `for every number z and every number x, there exists a unique number y such that x+y=z`. Then `given z rational and x irrational, the unique y found at the previous step must be ...`

Comment: Well y we know is a unique irrational or z-x

Comment: I don't get how splitting it up would help. I would just end up the same as the start right? Because I would go back to assuming z rational and X irrational

Comment: You know that $y=z-x$ is unique, so what remains to be shown is that it is irrational. By contradiction, if it were rational and given that $z$ is rational, then $x=z-y$ would be...

Comment: Then X would have to be rational @dxiv

Comment: Correct. But $x$ is known to be irrational, so that's a contradiction. Therefore the premise that $z$ was rational must be false.

Comment: @dxiv but how can I contradict a unique quantified? So instead of saying there exists a unique irrational y such that X+Y=z I would say there exists a unique rational y?

Comment: That $y$ is unique was established at the previous step. The only question left after that is whether that unique $y$ is rational or irrational. I think you are confusing yourself with those quantifiers, to the point of losing sight of what the question really means.

Comment: @dxiv oh so we are just contradicting rationality? But we have to prove that y is irrational so proving its rational would make this false?

Comment: $y=z-x$ is a unique real number. A real number is either rational or irrational. So, yes, once you prove (by contradiction) that $y$ can't be rational, then the conclusion is that it must be irrational.

Comment: @dxiv okay I'm still a bit lost as to how to set it up but it's making more sense now I think. Just making sure, we can keep the fact that z is rational true correct? And we are also assuming X is rational?

Comment: No, we can't and don't assume that $x$ is rational. Hope it's more clear in the posted answer.

Comment: You said X=z-y would have to be rational but since it's irrational this is a contradiction. Then z cannot be rational. But we are assuming it is rational. Then wouldn't this not be proving the point?

Comment: Please re-read my answer. It proves that $y$ (a) exists, (b) is unique, and (c) is irrational. It makes no additional assumptions on $z$ or $x$ other than those stated in the premise of the question, which is that $z$ is rational and $x$ irrational.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. You just sort of broke it down to prove y is in fact irrational. There was no change in X or z we just changed them around to prove the point?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Okay thank you. I just didn't understand that we could us the real numbers as the universe in our proof

Comment: Yes, real numbers *is* the universe to work in. Any time you have rationals and irrationals related by operations (`+`) and equality (`=`) those only make sense in a universe that encompasses both rationals and irrationals, (the smallest of) which is the real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> prove that for every rational number z

Let $z \in \mathbb{Q}$ be an arbitrary rational number.

> and every irrational number x,

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ be an arbitrary irrational number.

> there exists a unique irrational number y such that x+y=z

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be the unique real number defined by $y = z - x$.

Then $y$ (like all reals) is either rational or irrational.

Suppose $y$ were rational. Then $x = z - y$ would be the difference of two rational numbers, thus itself a rational number. But that contradicts the premise that $x$ is irrational, so the assumption that $y$ was rational is proven false. Therefore $y$ is irrational.

Comment: Oh okay I get it now! Could I split the y into two cases of y is rational and y is irrational.

Comment: No, because y **cannot** be rational!